# Check if an element is already in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list 1 with some elements.
Then I ask the user to add some elements to the list. This I do by creating a new list: list_added.
I want to add the list_added to the original list (using list.extend(list_added)). But before I do that. I want to check if an element that I've added is already in the original list. And if so the lists shall not be added together.

So if
list = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
and
list_added = ["D", "H"]

then I dont want the lists to add. How could I do this?

Comment: you should try this: list = list + [i for i in list_added if i not in list]

Comment: have you tried anything so far? what about the code to get the user input

Comment: Does order in list matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I'd do it is to use an unordered `set`, which assumes that ordering of elements in the collection doesn't matter.

Below is an example that shows two ways to add elements to a set - either extending the set with an existing list, or adding elements one at a time.

```py
my_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
my_set = set(my_list)

list_added = ["D", "H"]

# update with new elements
my_set.update(list_added)

# no duplicates
print(my_set)
# {'A', 'H', 'C', 'D', 'B'}

# reset the set elements
my_set = set(my_list)

for elem in list_added:
    my_set.add(elem)

print(my_set)
# {'A', 'H', 'C', 'D', 'B'}
```